# VS2015 Diagnose tool window does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I worked a long time with my visual studio 2015 without of these errors. Since some day two weeks ago I have the following problem:

When I want to start my application in visualstudio in "DEBUG"-mode it runs, but the "diagnose tool"-window is missing (where I see CPU, Events, ...). After I start the window manually, it has only one phrase as content "the diagnosetool does not support the current debug configuration. ("das diagnosetools unterstützt die aktuelle debug konfiguration nicht"). I checked under "Extras>Option>Debugging>General" if the tools are enabled. Yes, they are.

Sometimes the "diagnose tools" also show an other message like "diagnose tools has an unexcepted error. please look in diagnosehub". In the hub I see the message "class not registered".

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the *.suo-file not helps. After repair vs-studio over windows "add/remove programms" it runs corretly, but this action needs 3 hours by me.

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could mark your own answer so that it will help other community members search and handle similar issues:)

Comment: Correct, thanks for your reminder. Unfortunately I had to wait some days for that action.